# Java script básico

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de fazer uma verificação no meu código, um "if else", que quando eu não coloque nada pra calcular e clique no botão, ele dê um alerta avisando que não tem nada nos campos de valor.

Não peguei muito bem a lógica, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
document.getElementById("btn-calcular").onclick = function(){

    var valorA = document.getElementById("valor-a").value;
    var valorB = document.getElementById("valor-b").value;

    alert(parseInt(valorA) + parseInt(valorB));

    document.getElementById("resposta").value = parseInt(valorA) + parseInt(valorB);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas se for o que eu percebi pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById("btn-calcular").onclick = function(){

var valorA = document.getElementById("valor-a").value;
var valorB = document.getElementById("valor-b").value;

if (valorA == "" || valorB == ""){
   alert("Por favor introduza os dados necessários");
}
else{
    alert(parseInt(valorA) + parseInt(valorB));

 //aqui ja nao precisa de usar o parseInt, uma vez que ja converteu os valores para inteiros acima

    document.getElementById("resposta").value = valorA + valorB;

 }

}
```

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo. Valeuuuuuuuuuuuu de verdade! Abraço

Comment: Valeu ;) Força aí, pratique muito!